# In UI automator viewer Error Obtaining Device screenshot, Reason : Error Unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly

Tags: android, android-emulator, ui-automation

When I click on UI Automator viewer --> Device screenshot throws Error Unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly.

I am trying to run it Appium. I am able to load the apk in the emulator, stuck on the UI Automator viewer due to the adb connection error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Open with text editor (notepad/vim) the uiautomatorviewer.bat.

Find that line:

```
call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=%prog_dir%" -jar %jarpath% %*
```

and change it to `call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=C:\DEV\androidSDK\tools" -jar %jarpath% %*`

Please notice that you should put your Tools' path after the **bindir**.

Comment: It worked for me as well. Just edited the path in "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=<path on my machine>".
Great save on time. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Another fix is to just copy adb.exe next to the uiautomatorviewer.bat.

If I remember correctly, modified files can confuse Android Studio when updating SDK, so you have to manually delete in order to successfully update, meaning more future proof solution. Example: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKkWA.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that the uiautomatorviewer location was `user/library/android/sdk/tools/bin` and I was using it via `$ uiautomatorviewer`. The app was working correctly, but when I tried to get the view hierarchy adb error occured. Solution? Open it via `$ open uiautomatorviewer` xD

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I stopped Appium server and retried.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `adb.exe` into `uiautomatorviewer.bat` folder.

Answer (score -2):

Find the following code in UIautomatorviewer

call

> "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%"
>   "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=**%prog_dir%**" -jar %jarpath% %*

Set the bindir path to adb exe. path.

Or simply paste `adb.exe` with uiautomatorViewer