# unable to connect adb check if adb is installed properly on ubuntu

Tags: appium, ui-automation

Even though am able to see the devices
mosheko@vta065l:~/Downloads/tools/bin$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
05edfc9d9359e4b0    device

Am not able to see the devices

[image: Unable to see device]

Comment: Did you add ANDROID_SDK and the required system variables? You can find the details here https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696158/in-ui-automator-viewer-error-obtaining-device-screenshot-reason-error-unable/43136289